# Golang libraries for communicating with the Cardano blockchain

Tags: library

Is there a reliable Golang library available for communicating with the Cardano blockchain or the blockchain within the Cardano network, and is it freely available for use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these?

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/echovl/cardano-go

https://github.com/blinklabs-io/gouroboros

There is also the potential to use blockfrost in golang to access it as well. I have personally used this, and while limited, it is great to getting data.

https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-go